# Getting rid of a floor function in the next expression:$\left\lfloor\frac{(x-2)^2}{4}\right\rfloor $, It is known x is odd.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I was wondering if there's a way in which you can get rid of a floor function in the next expression:$$\left\lfloor\frac{(x-2)^2}{4}\right\rfloor $$ It is known x is odd.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Since $x$ is odd, $x=2n+1$ for some integer $n$, and therefore $(x-2)^2=(2n-1)^2=4n^2-4n+1$. Thus,

$$\left\lfloor\frac{(x-2)^2}4\right\rfloor=\left\lfloor n^2-n+\frac14\right\rfloor=n^2-n\;.$$

And $n=\dfrac{x-1}2$, so the expression reduces to

$$\left(\frac{x-1}2\right)^2-\frac{x-1}2=\frac{x^2-4x+3}4\;.$$

Comment: Thank you very much. Your answers are always helpful. So we get rid of the floor function because n is integer, so it's square and it's $n$ are both same but 1/4 becomes 0 thus floor is removed please?

Comment: @Avv: You’re very welcome.  You can’t simply break $\left\lfloor n^2-n+\frac14\right\rfloor$ up as $\lfloor n^2\rfloor-\lfloor n\rfloor$+$\left\lfloor\frac14\right\rfloor$ and treat each term separately, but but clearly $$n^2-n\le n^2-n+\frac14<n^2-n+1\,,$$ and $n^2-n$ and $n^2-n+1$ are consecutive integers, so by definition $\left\lfloor n^2-n+\frac14\right\rfloor=n^2-n$.

Answer (score 3):

Another way to look at it:

If is $x$ is odd, then $x-2$ is odd as well. We have that $x-2 \equiv 1$ (mod 4) or $ x-2 \equiv 3$ (mod 4). In either case we have that $(x-2)^2 \equiv 1$ (mod 4). 
Hence 4 divides $(x-2)^2-1$, therefore:

$$\left\lfloor\frac{(x-2)^2}4\right\rfloor= \frac{(x-2)^2-1}4$$

If you expand $(x-2)^2-1$, you get the same answer as the one given by Brian M. Scott.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:$$\left\lfloor\frac{(x-2)^2}{4}\right\rfloor=\frac{(x-2)^2}4-0.25$$

More generally:
 $$\left\lfloor x\right\rfloor=x-(x \mod 1)$$